# Php- I have not got my output for download corrupted files

Tags: php, upload

I am not able to open the file after the download.

It says the the file has been corrupted.

I guess i have used all the required headers fine.

In chrome it shows error like:
chrome resource interpreted as document but transferred with mime type application/octet-stream

In Firefox no error msg.

```
if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file']) {
$filename = $_GET['file'];
} else {
$filename = NULL;
}

$err = 'Sorry, the file you are requesting is unavailable.';
if ($filename)  {
// define the path to your download folder plus assign the file name
$path = '/wp-content/uploads/'. $filename;
// check that file exists and is readable


if (file_exists($path)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. basename($path) . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
            ob_end_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($path);
            exit;
        }


    }
```

download: getting downloaded from ftp folder.

None of the formats are opening.

.txt is getting opened.
  Let me know if i am in wrong direction.

Inserting into table:

```
echo "<tr><a href='?file=". $row["FileupName"]."'>".$row["FileupName"]."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Plus, it also informs the system that a solution was found for the ones who have provided you with solutions ;-)

Comment: I see `$_GET['file']` but it's unclear as to where that is coming from. Usually when it's "files related", it requires a POST method and a valid enctype, if this is coming from a form. Check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred i did even with a POST...its not getting downloaded itself... the related files are in the same page

Answer (score -1):

`readfile('$path')` is your issue, it should be `readfile($path)` (with no quotes)

In PHP, variables are only evaluated in strings if the string is defined in double quotes `"`. Effectively you're downloading a file where the contents is the literal string '$path', with an incorrect filesize.

Comment: i triedbut i am getting same error:Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:

Comment: Have you tried setting the content-type header to use the MIME type of the file you're trying to download? the [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function might be helpful